# Getting different errors while trying to solve converting strings to integers in a list

Tags: python, list, error-handling, xor

I've got the following list & string:

```
befcodes = ["A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20"]
telegram = "$00;02;A1;00000000*49"
```

My code now changes `A1` in the string 20 times like this:

```
allbefcodes = []
for i in befcodes:
    dif_tele = telegram.replace("A1", i)
    allbefcodes.append(dif_tele)
print (allbefcodes)
```

Which outputs the following list:

```
['$00;02;A1;00000000*49', '$00;02;A2;00000000*49', '$00;02;A3;00000000*49', '$00;02;A4;00000000*49', '$00;02;A5;00000000*49', '$00;02;A6;00000000*49', '$00;02;A7;00000000*49', '$00;02;A8;00000000*49', '$00;02;A9;00000000*49', '$00;02;10;00000000*49', '$00;02;11;00000000*49', '$00;02;12;00000000*49', '$00;02;13;00000000*49', '$00;02;14;00000000*49', '$00;02;15;00000000*49', '$00;02;16;00000000*49', '$00;02;17;00000000*49', '$00;02;18;00000000*49', '$00;02;19;00000000*49', '$00;02;20;00000000*49']
```

Now I want to use the XOR Operator in order to get a binary checksum of each telegram (=each charakter of `allbefcodes`) which I did like this:

```
result = functools.reduce(operator.xor,(ord(n) for n in (allbefcodes[0])[1:18]))  
print (f'{result:08b}')
```

That does work fine  for `allbefcodes[0]`, i get the output `01001001`. But I now want to do this for all charakters of `allbefcodes` with a loop, where I'm getting different errors..**here's what I tried so far:**

```
for x in allbefcodes:
    result = functools.reduce(operator.xor,(ord(n) for n in (allbefcodes[x])[1:18]))  
    print (f'{result:08b}')
```

The error `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` occurs. I tried to solve it like this:

```
for x in allbefcodes:
    allbefcodes = (int(a) for a in allbefcodes)
    result = functools.reduce(operator.xor,(ord(n) for n in (allbefcodes[x])[1:18]))  # "
    print (f'{result:08b}')
```

But here the error `TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable` occurs. So I tried this next:

```
allbefcodes = []
for i in befcodes:
    dif_tele = telegram.replace("A1", i)
    allbefcodes.append(dif_tele)
allbefcodes = (int(a) for a in allbefcodes)     #Tried to solve it with this line
print (allbefcodes)    

for x in allbefcodes:
    result = functools.reduce(operator.xor,(ord(n) for n in (allbefcodes[x])[1:18]))  # "(allbefcodes[0])" statt telegram
    print (f'{result:08b}')
```

But now the error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$00;02;A1;00000000*49'` occurs. Doing `(float(int(a)) for a in allbefcodes)` doesn't change that.
My last try was changing `(allbefcodes[x])` to `(allbefcodes[0:])` and leaving `allbefcodes = (int(a) for a in allbefcodes)`  out, like this:

```
allbefcodes = []
for i in befcodes:
    dif_tele = telegram.replace("A1", i)
    allbefcodes.append(dif_tele)
print (allbefcodes)    

for x in allbefcodes:
    result = functools.reduce(operator.xor,(ord(n) for n in (allbefcodes[0:])[1:18]))  # "(allbefcodes[0])" statt telegram
    print (f'{result:08b}')
```

But now I get `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 21 found`, which brings me back to needing integers instead of strings again, which I already tried to solve...I seriously don't know what to do anymore and would really appreciate some help!

Comment: The error you found `TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable` happened because you used a comprehension delimited by parantheses, which creates a generator. The last line with `TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 21 found` have happened because you are iterating over a list where each entry is an element in  `allbefcodes`, which is a `string of length 21`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!
I just had to replace `(allbefcodes[0:])` with `x` like this:

```
allbefcodes = []
for i in befehlscodes:
    dif_tele = telegram.replace("A1", i)
    allbefcodes.append(dif_tele)
print (allbefcodes)
   
for x in allbefcodes:
    result = functools.reduce(operator.xor,(ord(n) for n in x[1:18]))
```